# Configuration of nginx as reserve proxy for apache - installing ossn open source social network

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, proxy

This is my first post here. I've always tried to figure things out by myself and find solutions in previously asked questions. Well, for 3 days now I'm trying to set up an nginx server for an ossn ([open source social network](https://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/)).

So i followed [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04/) for my basic set up.
After finishing the guide of this tutorial i see the same info.php 
but i can't run my php scripts of the app successfully. The CMS is working with 
dynamic URLs. Switching cases for specific URI parts etc... 
So the accessed domains are not necessarily reffering with a  *.php

I'm very new to linux. While trying to configure nginx I've often end up in a bad gateway or 404. The info php works fine. As soon as i want to access the root of my cms, i got a file not found by apache.

It would be great if you could have a glimpse.

Greets Jules

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;
```

is set.

```
nginx -t
```

tells me that the syntax is ok and status of Apache2 and Nginx ist "active".

My Apache2 log:

```
 [Wed Feb 01 07:29:29.287223 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6941] AH01909: ellingtons-palace.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Feb 01 10:18:39.179882 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4514] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Feb 01 10:18:40.142089 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5128] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 01 10:18:40.142155 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5128] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

My Nginx Error log produces hundreds of this logs:

```
2017/02/01 10:18:16 [alert] 4554#4554: socketpair() failed while spawning "worker process" (24:$ Toom many files open)
```

As you see in my Nginx-configuration, i tried to increase the worker_processes

my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1024;

# set open fd limit to 30000
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections 2048;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml appli$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Server :

```
upstream ellingtons-palace.test {
    server ellingtons-palace.test:8000;
}



server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    client_header_buffer_size 32k;
    client_body_buffer_size 10M;

    root /var/www/html/ellingtons-palace.test/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name *.ellingtons-palace.test www.ellingtons-palace.test;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://ellingtons-palace.test/:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            autoindex on;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
            #expires      48h;
    }
    location @proxy {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
    location ~* \.php$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

}
```

My Port usage:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1893/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1396/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4554/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1396/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1045/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       5128/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1396/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4554/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN       1045/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      5128/apache2
```

unfortunately all this leads to a boring 404

```
root@jwmc-server:/var/log/nginx# curl -I ellingtons-palace.test
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 09:33:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
```